# Can Python packages installed through Jupyter Notebook be used offline? Vice versa

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, command-prompt, python-packaging

I used `!pip install <package-name>` to install required packages in a Jupyter Notebook.

If I want to run the scripts offline, e.g. through the Command Prompt, do I need to `pip install` the same package again in Command Prompt? Or are the packages I install through Jupyter Notebook also consumed by a Command Prompt run?

What about vice versa? (i.e. can packages installed through Command Prompt be consumed by Jupyter Notebook script run)

I get different list of packages when doing `pip list` in Command Prompt vs `!pip list` in Jupyter Notebook, hence I assume these are stored in different places and are not shared? Therefore my guess is I do have to install twice?

But, running the below script in both Command Prompt and Jupyter Notebook returns the same list of results (list of locations where the system looks for packages), no matter what paths I add as environment variables. And the returned path is basically where Jupyter Notebook-installed packages are stored. So does that mean only packages installed through Jupyter Notebook are needed and matter?

```
import sys
sys.path
```

Answer (score 0):

That `!pip install` is actually being run in a shell, so it's the same as if you did it from the command line. The trick is that if you're running in a virtual environment or condo environment, it's going to be installed in the virtual environment. If you leave the notebook you may not be in the same virtual environment so it won't be found.